# Return a string result from a named query in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, named-query

How to return String type result in a named query which is of type Query....
the code i tried

```
public String getTargetEmail(){
    Query query= em.createNamedQuery("BC_READ_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_BY_NAME");
    return (String)query.toString();
}
```

but this return something else like `org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl@3e4d072b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling **toString** on Query object, you just get a string representation of it. You need actually to execute the query like this

```
return (String) query.getSingleResult();
```

Ensure that the query always returns only one result, otherwise calling **getSingleResult**, will throw a **NonUniqueResultException** exception in case more one result that one is returned, or **NoResultException** in case no result is returned (check documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult%28%29))

Comment: If your query returns multiple rows you should use `getResultList` instead